# Проблема с триггерами в unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 объекта, оба Image, в Canvas. Фиолетовый куб, движется к зеленому и должен удаляться, при столкновении, но этого не происходит, что можно сделать?

Первый объект, фиолетовый куб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй объект, зеленый куб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    Debug.Log('1');
    Destroy(col.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На один объект нужно добавить **Rigidbody2D**.

Comment: Я над этим сидел с 14:00, по 22:00, благодарствую.